# Create an user with firebase-admin, nodejs and angular 6

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, angular6, firebase-admin

I want -as an admin- to create an user with firebase-admin using node.js and handle all that inside an Angular 6 App.

The firebase-admin in node.js works like a charm but when I have to implement the functions to handle the user creation and stuff like that is when I am stuck to.

So, the main question is: **how can I edit my server code to get the input data from my angular app and then create the user with those values?** I tried with

```
router.route('/patient-add').get((req, res) => {
  if (res.send) {
    admin.auth().createUser({
      email: req.body.email
     })
```

but no response whatsoever.

Here is my nodejs code (server.js)

```
import express from 'express';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import cors from 'cors';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const superserviceadminKey = 'path/to/serviceAccountKey.json';

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(superserviceadminKey),
  databaseURL: 'https://mysuperdatabase.firebaseio.com'
});

app.use('/', router);

router.route('/patient-add').get((req, res) => {
  if (res.send) {
    admin.auth().createUser({
      email: "someemail2@gmail.com",
      emailVerified: false,
      phoneNumber: "+198089930",
      password: "secretPassword",
      displayName: "Luciphagous, the dog",
      photoURL: "http://www.example.com/12345678/photo.png"
     })
      .then(function(userRecord) {
        // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
        console.log("Successfully created new user:", userRecord.uid);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error creating new user:", error);
      });
  }
});

app.listen(6666, () => console.log('Express server running on port 6666'));
```

As I said before, the code above works perfectly fine; the problem is that I have to put the values before create the user in Firebase. May I get the values from a HTML form and inject them from front-end to back-end?

So, I guessed I could handle that with Angular and I created a service. Here is the code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  uri = 'http://localhost:6666';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  createUser(displayName, email, pass, phoneNumber) {
    const userReg = {
      displayName: displayName,
      email: email,
      password: pass,
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber
    };
    return this.http.post(`${this.uri}/patient-add`, userReg);
  }
}
```

When I execute it in my Angular App, I receive this error:

```
patients-add.component.ts:28 HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://localhost:4000/patient-add", ok: false, …}
```

Line 28 of patients-add.component.ts is this:

```
this.auth.createUser('John Doe', 'hello@gmail.com', 'superpassword', '+12389298').toPromise().then(result => {
  console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Thanks in advance to everyone!

Comment: I wish I had more advice to give, but I notice in your error it lists `"http://localhost:4000/patient-add"` instead of the `"http://localhost:6666/patient-add"` you're trying to reach, right? It's always possible I'm entirely off, but I figured it's worth a try.

Comment: @JenPerson thanks for your response. And yeah, that was part of the error. Also, I had another tiny error when get the http request in my angular code. But everything is working fine now. Thanks again!